# Rails: One-to-many foreign key incorrect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, foreign-keys, one-to-many, shoulda

I am relatively new to rails. I am trying to set a one-to-many association in rails. However, I think I am doing something wrong with my foreign_key since my test is failing. My test is the following:

In user_spec:

```
  it {should have_many :invitations}
```

User model:

```
  has_many :invitations
```

Invitations model:

```
belongs_to :sender, :class_name => "User"
```

Invitation migration:

```
class CreateInvitations < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :invitations do |t|
      t.integer :sender_id
      t.string :token

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

The error I get from the test is:

```
Failure/Error: it {should have_many :invitations}
       Expected User to have a has_many association called invitations (Invitation does not have a user_id foreign key.)
```

I am not sure where I am going wrong. Any ideas?

Comment: t.integer :sender_id change to t.integer :user_id in migration

Comment: ok, makes sense. I got this part of the migration from a railcast. http://railscasts.com/episodes/124-beta-invitations
if i wanted to keep :sender_id in migration (in case i bring in recipient_id too ... how could I adjust my code?

Comment: Use `:foreign_key`. See my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fivell is right. You just used an alias for a association to the User class. Either change the column name to `user_id` or tell rails to use another foreign key:

*invitation.rb*

```
belongs_to :sender, :class_name => "User"
```

*user.rb*

```
has_many :invitations, :foreign_key => "sender_id"
```

Comment: this brought the same error. I added ":foreign_key => "sender_id" ... it made no difference

Comment: I didnt expect this to fix the error since by convention rails makes the foreign_key = {association_name}_id

Comment: Did you restart the server/console? And as you see, rails was looking for `user_id` in you question. It takes the real association name, not the alias.

Answer (score 4):

Error shows that problem is not in belongs_to, but in has_many

```
 has_many :invitations , :foreign_key => "sender_id"
```

Comment: Thanks, overlooked this one. I fixed my answer.

Comment: This fixed it! Probably a beginners question to rails, but could you please explain why I would have to add this, when the invitation key already knows that the sender's foreign key is sender id?

Comment: No, you can remove it from the `invitation.rb`. You just need to declare it  once, but in the right place. You tell rails to associate User with many invitations using the foreign key "sender_id". This is the right way.

Comment: Klump, do you know why that is and why the guides make it seem like the foreign_key can go on either side of the association? It seems like a bug in the guide to me. https://gist.github.com/michaeldhopkins/edc01146f11b24208da3